# Sklearn Calibration Curve on Machine Learning Models Issue

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have attempted to plot the Calibration Curves on below 5 Machine Learning Models and the result didn't feel right. First, the Regression Model curve is not showing, second can someone help me analyze the plot? Much appreciated. It is almost don't feel right that the Decision Tree curve is perfectly aligned with the perfectly calibrated dotted line.Feel free to pinpoint any mistakes you see in my code logic.
In addition, the code output has an error message of **"invalid value encountered in true_divide"** despite the output has produced a graph.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn
import scikitplot as skplt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV, CalibrationDisplay
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC

from sklearn import metrics
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator


lr_probas = LogisticRegression().fit(X_train, y_train).predict_proba(X_test)
rf_probas = RandomForestClassifier().fit(X_train, y_train).predict_proba(X_test)
dt_probas = DecisionTreeClassifier().fit(X_train, y_train).predict_proba(X_test)
svm_probas = SVC(probability=True).fit(X_train, y_train).predict_proba(X_test)
xgb_probas = XGBClassifier().fit(X_train, y_train).predict_proba(X_test)

probas_list = [lr_probas, rf_probas, dt_probas, svm_probas, xgb_probas]
clf_names =["Logistic Regression", "Random Forest","Decision Tree Classifier", "Support Vector Machines", "XGBoost" ]
clf_list = [(lr_probas, "Logistic Regression"), 
            (rf_probas, "Random Forest"), 
            (dt_probas, "Decision Tree"),
            (svm_probas, "Support Vector Machine"),
            (xgb_probas, "XGBoost"),
           ]

ax =skplt.metrics.plot_calibration_curve(y_test, probas_list, clf_names, n_bins=15, figsize=(15,6));
# Set minor ticks/gridline cadence.
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))

# Turn minor gridlines on and make them thinner.
ax.grid(which='minor', linewidth=0.6)

plt.show()
```

I have not tried anything else because not sure where went wrong with this plot especially the curve for Logistic Regression is not showing.

[Calibration Plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggADx.png)

Comment: "second can someone help me analyze the plot?" this is off-topic here, see the Note in the [machine-learning tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info). Can you provide the dataset, or a version that reproduces the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: The dataset comes from this link on [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/shrutimehta/nasa-asteroids-classification), it's about NASA Asteroid Classification

Comment: I have fixed the issue and my calibration curve contains all the six Machine Learning Models now.